# Resolving Root Directory

Tags: image, relative-path

I'm using Visual Studio Web Developer Express on this website and lets say, for example, I have the following directory structure ...

```
<root>\
<root>\index.htm
<root>\images\
<root>\images\logo.png
<root>\myfolder\
<root>\myfolder\index.htm
```

In the \index.htm I can load my image into the page with ...

```
<img src="images\logo.png" />
```

In the \myfolder\index.htm page, I can load my image with ...

```
<img src="\images\logo.png" />
```

This works fine on the server, but in VWD I just get the broken link image.  How can I set this in VWD to recognize that \images\logo.png points to the root directory, then the images folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the property pages window for the entire website, I see the virtual directory property and I set it to

```
/
```

Everything now shows correctly in VWD.